# customize spring security

Tags: java, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have problem wuth spring security.

I am finally confused.
I want to make so:

1.after invoke `spring_secutity_check`

a) if good login and password - go to `/successLogin`

b) wrong credentials - go to `/badLogin`

2 after invocation `j_spring_security_logout`  go to `/logouUrl`

Can you help configure configuration for my conditions ?

Answer (score 0):

refer to "Spring in action ch:9 page no 230"

Answer (score 0):

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <!--
    ......
    -->

    <http auto-config="true">
        <form-login 
            login-page="/login" 
            default-target-url="/successLogin"
            authentication-failure-url="/badLogin" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logoutUrl" />
    </http>

    <!--
    ......
    -->

</beans:beans>
```